# Angle of a regular simplex

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I find the following question embarrassing, but I have not been able to either resolve it, or to find a reference.

> What is the vertex angle of a regular $n$-simplex?

Background: For a vertex $v$ in a convex polyhedron $P$, the vertex angle at $v$ is the proportion of the volume that $P$ occupies in a small ball around $v$. In symbols, $$\angle v=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{|B(v,\varepsilon)\cap P|}{|B(v,\varepsilon)|}.$$ Up to normalization, this definition agrees with the familiar definition of the angles in the plane, or the solid angle in $3$-space.

Comment: You don't have to be embarrassed, since the question is to compute the volume of an $n-1$ dimensional spherical simplex (the one with interior dihedral angles $\alpha$, where $\cos\alpha = 1/n$ if I'm right), which could be hard if $n$ is large. At least, there is Schlafli differential formula, but I don't know if there is a "simple expression" only in terms, say, of $\Gamma$ function evaluation at rational numbers. I can only direct you to this paper http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/58/1/107.full 
and its references (notably Aomoto).

Comment: Your "vertex angle" is in fact $1/n$ times the usual solid angle (volume of the the spherical simplex in my comment), divided by the volume of $S^{n-1}$. This is of course due to the term $r^{n-1}dr$ under the volume integral in spherical coordinates. 

Comment: See [this meta note](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2587/6094) for citation of a recent paper on this topic: "Bounds for Pach's selection theorem and for the minimum solid angle in a simplex."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the paper by John Leech,
"Sphere packings in Higher Space"
*Canadian Journal of Mathematics*, 1964, which you can find at the [Google book links here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZgwT9xyHZ4gC&pg=PA675&lpg=PA675&dq=%25252522regular+simplex%25252522+solid+angle+at+vertex&source=bl&ots=Yx9JO0VskH&sig=YNEavV1sBX1jNc94ZWSqgwxRZCk&hl=en&ei=JqBGTZ6_CYv4gAeewbXyAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=%22regular%20simplex%22%20solid%20angle%20at%20vertex&f=false),
the following formulas are given for the "solid angular content at each vertex of a regular simplex":

$$2^{-n} n! f_n(n) H_n$$

where

$$H_n = 2 \pi^{\frac{1}{2}n} / \Gamma(n/2)$$

is the total $(n{-}1)$-dimensional surface content,
$f_n(\sec 2 \alpha)=F_n(\alpha)$, and (finally!)
$F_n(\alpha)$ is Schläfli's function mentioned by BS in his comment.
This function is discussed in Section 7.2 (p.107ff) of
Chuanming Zong's book, *Sphere Packings* ([Google books link here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ScdN96_Ux-oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zong+sphere+packings&source=bl&ots=l5g1c8RkZi&sig=cspsXdNQYQzLiaV5wGsbxRhOBcI&hl=en&ei=5qxGTfX0CoucgQfLutyYAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q&f=false))
and in
the paper, "Analytic structure of Schläfli function,"
Kazuhiko Aomoto,
[*Nagoya Math. J.* Volume 68 (1977), 1-16](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-68/issue-none/Analytic-structure-of-Schl%C3%A4fli-function/nmj/1118796538.full),
also mentioned by BS.
Rogers computed an asymptotic formula for $F_n(\alpha)$:

$$ \frac{ \sqrt{ 1+cn}} {\sqrt{2} e^{1/c} n!} \left( \frac{2 e}{\pi c n} \right) ^{n/2} \;,$$

where
$c = (\sec 2 \alpha - (n-1))^{-1}$.

Comment: so, after pluggin in $\sec 2\alpha = n$, we get that the vertex angle is $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{2}e} \cdot \left(\frac{2e}{\pi n}\right)^{n/2} \cdot \frac{H_n}{2^n}$, which is, asymptotically, $2^{-\Theta(n\log n)}\cdot H_n$. Right?

Comment: @JanKyncl: You're ahead of me on this. That does seem correct.

Answer (score 3):

In Theorem 1 in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0893-9659%2898%2900117-7) (also citation 3 in that paper), a different definition of the vertex angle is given, with the value for the regular simplex computed. If you combine that with the description in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersine.html), you should be able to get an expression for your expression up there.

Comment: I saw this paper, but I could not figure why the definition in this paper is consistent with the definition of the angle I gave. Also, from the formula in the paper, in dimension 3 I do not get the answer I expect.

Comment: Right, which is why I said it is a different definition (I also checked the case in 3D). I was being hopeful that with a bit of massaging around there may be a simple closed-form expression connecting that definition to your definition. But maybe I was being too optimistic. 

Comment: The determinant in that definition "approximates" the volume of the polar spherical simplex. If the given spherical simplex is 

considered as a cone bounded by $n$ hyperplanes, then any of the $2^n$ cones gives the same angle by this definition, but their real angles may be very different. (The formula was proved also in citation [2], which is in Czech).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to the original [paper by Rogers](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-36/1/78.extract) mentioned by Joseph O'Rourke in his answer, with a short proof of the asymptotic formula for $F_n(\alpha)$, which is reproduced in the book Sphere Packings by Chuanming Zong.

It is also shown there that the multiplicative error in the formula is at most $1+ \frac{31}{12n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ in the case of the regular simplex, where $\sec 2\alpha=n$ (and thus $c=1$, or, $b=1$ in the paper).